# Страница не найдена. Python/Django

Tags: python, django

Почему так происходит? Делаю все по инструкции т.к. учусь. 
urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url,include
from django.contrib import admin
from . import views 
urlpatterns = [
    #url(r'^$',views.main,name="main"),
    url(r'^post/(?P<id>[0-9]+)/', views.post_detail, name='post_detail'),
]
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.utils import timezone
from .models import Post
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
# Create your views here.

def post_detail(request,id):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=id)
    return render(request, 'main/post_detail.html', {'post': post})
```

post_detail.html

```
{% extends 'main/base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    <div class="post">
        {% if post.published_date %}
            <div class="date">
                {{ post.published_date }}
            </div>
        {% endif %}
        <h1>{{ post.title }}</h1>
        <p>{{ post.text|linebreaksbr }}</p>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Что делать? Даже вместо id ставил pk, но ничего не помогает.

[image: Страница не найдена]

Comment: может поста с айдишником "1" нет в базе?

Comment: @IvanSemochkin есть. я сам в admin panel создавал посты

Comment: может первый пост был удален и потом созданы еще несколько, соответственно id "1" уже в базе нет.

Comment: @IvanSemochkin ничего не изменилось. пост с ид 4 существует, но ссылка не работает. [id 4](https://prnt.sc/h9gwtq)

Comment: Этот urls.py единственный в проекте?

Answer (score 1):

попробуй поставить в конце обьяления ссылки $

либо импорт views сделай по полному пути, такое ощущение, что urls.py и views.py находятся у тебя в разных каталогах.

Answer (score 1):

url использует свой синтаксис, где ^ - открывающий элемент, а $ - закрывающий.
В вашем случае вы забыли поставить закрывающий, что можно заметить также по страничке с ошибкой, которая показывает вам шаблоны, в которые пыталась впихнуть вашу ссылку. Как раз вы ожидаете, что джанго пройдёт по 2 шаблону, но вместо второго шаблона вся строка кода.

Вот тут можно почитать про url:
https://tutorial.djangogirls.org/ru/django_urls/